# Why can not I have two page formats to a record type?

Tags: salesforce, recordtype

Why can not I have two or more page formats to a **record type?**

should I associate only one? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your page layout base on your recordtype and profiles so each profile can see a different page layout then other profiles on the same recordtype

so technically you can assign 2 or more page layouts for the same recordtype but one for each profile

Regards,